# TSQL to Calculate Total Time Between Log in and Log Out, Along with Time in Each State

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL table as below (Image 1)

[image: SQL Table]

I am trying to calculate the time difference each state and total duration between log in and log out for an agent as below.(Image 2).  I am trying to use lead/Lag functions but unable to achieve the output. Can you please help on this.

[image: Time In Each Stage and Final Desired Output]

Comment: Try posting text, not images. Also provide some **complete** sample input and output. You aren't showing any seconds in your current dataset but are showing that in the output. Also, what version of SQL? I assume 2012 given the LEAD/LAG but if you aren't on 2012 onward this function isn't available and you'll need to use a window function.

Comment: I have copied the results to an excel which has not showing the Seconds in it , I am using SQL 2012.

Comment: Include whatever you have done so far, and like already asked, instead of pictures, include proper examples.

Answer (score -1):

The snippet below should help you get going:

```
;WITH TotalDuration as 
(
    SELECT  LogIN = Min(DateTime)
            ,LogOut =   Max(DateTime)
            ,AgentID
    FROM    YourTable
    Group BY AgentID

)

SELECT Duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LogIN, LogOut)
        ,AgentId
FROM TotalDuration
ORDER BY  AgentId



--TimeInState = datediff(minute, [DateTime], LEAD([DateTime], 1) OVER (Partition BY AgentID ORDER BY [DateTime]))
```

Comment: OP is trying to aggregate time in all states (reserve, read, talk, etc...), not just login and log out.

Comment: Thanks for your response, When you mentioned Log in and Log Out as Min (datetime) and Max(Datetime) i need to restrict the duration for each day. I am trying to aggregate the time in all states along with total duration for each particular day. An Agent Comes tomorrow and log in and log out that needs to be seperate duration.

Answer (score -1):

I think you know how to get the total log in and log out time using min and max... here is the LEAD and LAG that you need.

```
with cte as(
    select
        agentid,
        eventtype,
        [DateTime], 
        datediff(mi,[DateTime],LEAD([DateTime]) over (partition by agentid order by [DateTime])) as [Time_in_state]
    from yourTable)

select
    agentid,
    eventtype,
    cast([DateTime] as Date) as TheDate,
    sum(Time_in_state) as TotalTime,
from cte
group by
    agentid,
    eventtype,
    cast([DateTime] as Date)
```

Comment: Anyone want to provide details on why this wasn't helpful or didn't work? :)'